# Fill in cells based on reference values from another df in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data-cleaning

I want to create a table that looks like this:

| ID | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 | 2003 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

where the value "1" is filled in the cells that correspond the reference values in another data frame.

The reference data frame would look like this:

| ID | Year |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2001 |
| B | 2000 |
| B | 2002 |

In my actual data, I have about 1500 ID's so manually doing this isn't really an option.
Any ideas on how I can make this happen? I'm assuming a for loop, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `pivot_wider` filling the missing values with `0`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  arrange(Year) %>% 
  mutate(value = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols ="ID", names_from = "Year", values_fill = 0)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  ID    `2000` `2001` `2002`
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 B          1      0      1
2 A          0      1      0
```

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you! 
I have an added question. My data set also has a location column. Would I be able to use this method but assign a different number for each location. For example, fill a 1 in the table for individuals caught at location 1, fill a 2 for location 2, etc. instead of just all 1s. (Also, not all locations have data from each year or else I would just do each separately then combine)